# Heroku: docker deploy throws unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple Flask server to Heroku using the following steps:

```
heroku login
heroku container:login

# create the app
heroku create myapp-name-2

# create the container with format:
# docker build -t registry.heroku.com/<app name>/<process type> .
docker build -t registry.heroku.com/myapp-name-2/web .

# push the image to the registry
docker push registry.heroku.com/myapp-name-2/web

# "release" the image
heroku container:release --app myapp-name-2 web

# open the app
heroku open --app myapp-name-2
```

However, the `docker push` step displays:

```
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/myapp-name-2/web]
f60f7a4e2b2a: Preparing
3ff8a98d192e: Preparing
71476851914e: Preparing
013688a141bb: Preparing
f09460ef2908: Preparing
e188a7526d55: Waiting
6b0d56603c0c: Waiting
9496e71377c6: Waiting
5710e17ef032: Waiting
9546672d6b2f: Waiting
f2c194ac8a61: Waiting
2a50ea4f9e8e: Waiting
634249d50b9e: Waiting
68e35493907b: Waiting
e84b9d651af1: Waiting
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Does anyone know how I should authenticate? I've run the `heroku login` and `heroku container:login` steps multiple times now but must be missing something!

Comment: Absolutely bizarre. Repeating the same steps with a different app name runs just fine...

Comment: Can you put your complete `docker login` commands please? I say that because if login fails, maybe you need your registry.heroku.com/myapp-name-2 in insecure registries in your /etc/docker/daemon.json

Comment: Hmm, that file (stored at `~/. docker/daemon. json` on OSX) only contained `{'debug': true, 'experimental': false}`. There were no insecure registries. The `heroku container:login` is just an alias, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

Comment: Did you get any further with this? Bashing my head against the wall with this exact same problem. For one app it works fine, the other doesn't. I tried the insecure registry but to no avail. And there is zero debug information..

Comment: And of course, 5 minutes after commenting this, I found out we had a typo in the heroku app name. *facepalm*

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: @MarkM I also struggled with this until I realised it was a typo!

Answer (score 32):

The same error occurred to me. I just ran the command below and it worked.

```
heroku container:login
```

Comment: Yes, I had run that command to no avail. I believe I hit the wrinkle in the space-time manifold where bits dance with elves instead of flying to their intended destination

Answer (score 16):

Yes, as the original answer points out first run

```
heroku container:login
```

But also ensure that the docker image is tagged correctly with the following naming convention:

```
docker tag <image> registry.heroku.com/<app>/<process-type>
```

`<app>` should exactly match your apps name in the dashboard of Heroku.

Additional information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-an-existing-image

Comment: this was helpful -> <app> should exactly match your apps name in the dashboard of Heroku. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

docker hub login before

heroku container:login

and
heroku container:push web --app app_name

heroku container:release web --app app_name

worked for me

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is always a good practice to write descriptive answers which can help large audience to understand it. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

So in my case it was a permissions issue. Ensure that the user has the 'Deploy' permission in Heroku.